# What is the difference between local_settings.py and settings.py in openstack_dashboard?

Tags: openstack, horizon

Hi i have installed openstack-dashboard and i  noticed that exists two files of configuration local_settings.py in /etc/openstack_dashboard and settings.py in /usr/share/openstack_dashboard so can you tell me the difference between them .
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The file in `/usr/share/openstack_dashboard/...` contains the default application settings.

The file `/etc/openstack_dashboard/local_settings.py` contains overrides that are particular to your environment.

You would edit the latter to make configuration changes in your environment, but not the former.  The file in `/usr/share/openstack_dashboard/...` will be replaced on package updates/new version installs, but the file in `/etc/openstack_dashboard` should be preserved on upgrades.

Comment: thank you for tyour  resonse but  realy i didn't understand the deffernce

Comment: I didn't understand why use 2 files instead just one file containing configuration

Comment: I thought I explained it pretty clearly: one file has the defaults, and will typically get replaced *automatically* on upgrades, meaning that you will lose any changes you make there.  The local_settings file is *yours*, that file will not be overwritten.